# Does Git have a mechanism to solve the issue of hundreds of small projects?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Let's say if we practice problem solving, and in each folder, we will have source code, sample input, output, and notes.  For independence, it may be good to keep each problem and folder as a separate Git repo.  And to safely back up the files, we can `git push` to GitHub or to GitLab.

It is also good to have the `git commit` comments separate from each other, as a comment for one problem, if mixed with comments for hundreds of other problems, then it can be chaotic.

But the problem arises when now we have 120 of such repos.  If we want to `git clone` all those questions to our other computer, we will have to `git clone` 120 times?  Is there a way to group or batch some repos together so that they belong to a group, or have a repo that contains 120 other small repos somehow?

Comment: How about git submodules https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule.
You could define your 120 repos as submodules to a bigger one. Then when cloning the main repo with `git clone --recursive` you would get all the submodules as well.

Comment: You may try submodules. Or, you can have all the folders in 1 repo and use sparse checkouts.

Comment: Try Google's REPO, a tool designed to manage Android code that has hundreds of git repositories.

Comment: Is separating commit messages the only problem with single repo for you? You can see git commit comments per given file or directory in a repo via `git log path`.

Answer (score 0):

`subtree merge` might be what you're looking for.
https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/

The alternative is also a third-party and well documented tool `git-subregion` https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo#readme

Very good git-subtree tutorial: https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec